# Strange Output from an HTML Template and Python progam

Tags: html, templates, python-3.5

I have an html template that pulls in subs from a Python Program.

The piece of the template I'm having trouble with is:

```
<span style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;font-size: 14px;">
<table style="font-size: 14px; color: #4d4d4d; line-height:16px; background-color:#ffffff;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
      $tracking_nos
</table></span><br>
```

My Code created the `tracking_nos` variable is:

```
if 'TRACKING' in comment_row[2]:
            tracking_line = comment_row[2]
            pos = tracking_line.find("1Z")
            tracking_no = tracking_line[pos: -1]
            subs['tracking_nos'].append('<tr><a href="http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?track=yes&trackNums=%s">Please click here to track your package</a></tr>' % (tracking_no.strip()))
```

I am not sure why I'm getting output that looks like the below text or how to determine what the issue is:

['Please click here to track your package']

Answer (score 0):

I worked this out by not appending the HTML to the list, but by creating the variable using HTML and iterating through the tracking nos list.

```
if len(subs['tracking_nos']) > 0:
         subs[
             'tracking_nos'] = '<tr><a href="http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/processRequest?%s&track.x=0&track.y=0">Please click here to track your shipments</a></tr>' % "&".join(
             ["InquiryNumber%d=%s" % (i + 1, d) for i, d in enumerate(subs['tracking_nos'])])
     else:
         subs['tracking_nos'] = ""
```